# Streams in java

Tags: java, client, io, stream

well, i am developing a single server multiple-client program in java. My problem is can i use single stream for all the clients or do i have  to create a seperate stream for each client?

please help
thank you

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you talking of network streams? Isn't it important from which client data arrives (which would defeat the single-stream-thing)?

Comment: Please make a more descriptive title for this question. "Streams in java" is way too broad. Make it something like: "Are multiple streams required for multiple clients?"

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd need a stream per client. In *some* cases you can get away with UDP and multicasting, but it doesn't sound like a great idea for a chat server.

Usually it's easy to get a stream per client with no extra work, because each client will connect to the server anyway, and a stream can easily be set up over that connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but I think it would be harder.

If you're using **[java.net.ServerSocket](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)** then each client accepted through:

```
Socket client = server.accept();
```

Will have it's own stream so you don't have to do anything else.

Is there a real need for a single stream for all clients or is just something you think it would help.

For the later it could cause more problems than those is solve.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you do it?**
Yes, as Jon Skeet said, you can use multicasting.

**Should you do it?**
That depends on what you are using the streams for.

For most client server applications, you will need a stream per client to maintain independent communications.  Of course, there are applications where using multicasting is the right approach, such as live video streaming.  In such a case, you would not want to overwhelm your network while streaming the same data to multiple clients.  Of course, even in this case there will typically be a single control channel of some sort between each client and server.